# Cannot install mpi4py using conda AND specify pre-installed mpicc path

Tags: python, anaconda, mpi, conda, mpi4py

I have tried installing `mpi4py` with:

```
env MPICC=path/to/openmpi/bin/mpicc conda install -c anaconda mpi4py
```

But I get this message:

```
The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:
  mpi                anaconda/linux-64::mpi-1.0-mpich
  mpi4py             anaconda/linux-64::mpi4py-3.0.3-py37h028fd6f_0
  mpich              anaconda/linux-64::mpich-3.3.2-hc856adb_0
```

Which seems to show that "MPICC=path/to/openmpi/bin/mpicc" was ignored.

Indeed, after installing `mpi4py` with mpich, and trying to run the following simple code with `mpirun -n 2 python mpi4pyTest.py`:

```
from mpi4py import MPI
comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
size = comm.Get_size()
rank = comm.Get_rank()
print('Hello from processor {} of {}'.format(rank+1,size))
```

The output is:

```
Hello from processor 1 of 1
Hello from processor 1 of 1
```

How can I get conda to link `mpi4py` with my own mpicc? Its location is setup in PATH environment variable, as well as LD_LIBARY_PATH.

Best regards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`conda install` pulls precompiled binary packages and their dependencies from the repository. If you want `mpi4py` built with your own MPI implementation, use `pip` instead to install from source. You can use `pip` with Conda environments.

#### Edit for completion

Either uninstall all packages using `conda remove` and then install `mpi4py` using `pip` (specifying the MPICC environment variable to your MPI C complier), OR start with a new environment.

Comment: Thank you Hristo Iliev! Your answer didn't completely fix my issue, but I was able to base mysef on it to find a fix.

Comment: @Breno Well, I assumed you've uninstalled the conda packages or started with a new environment. In any case, glad you've managed to get it running.

Comment: I've edited your answer with my "fix". I'll wait for the edit to be approved, then delete my own answer. Cheers!

Comment: Neither worked for me in a `conda` env. In my case it worked when I installed it in a `python3-env`. Weird!