# Issue installing petsc4py with Anaconda using pip, to indicate external PETSc directory

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, mpi4py, petsc

## I) The issue

I cannot install `petsc4py` in my Anaconda environment using `pip`.

Installing with `conda` doesn't work because it won't check my predefined PETSC_DIR  and PETSC_ARCH environment variables during installation. `numpy` and `cython` are installed.

The error output by `pip install` is shown in section **IV**, below.

## II) Versions

I have Ananconda 2020.02, installed with Python 3.7. My OS is Ubuntu 18.04.

## III) Reproducing the issue

### 1) Make a user installation of [OpenMPI](https://www.open-mpi.org/software/ompi/v4.0/) 4.0.3

Configured using

```
--prefix="/home/$USER/.openmpi" CC=gcc FC=gfortran
```

Then `make` and `make install`.

Add `.openmpi/bin` file to PATH and add `.openmpi/lib` to LD_LIBRARY_PATH:

```
export PATH=/home/$USER/.openmpi/bin:$PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/home/$USER/.openmpi/lib/
```

### 2) Install [PETSc](https://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/download/index.html) 3.13

Configured indicating `mpicc` and `mpifort` from `/home/$USER/.openmpi/bin` and downloading blas/lapack, scalapack, MUMPS, METIS, PARMETIS and PTSCOTCH, with -O2 compiler optimization (Note: I used MKL for blas/lapack and scalapack). Also indicate `PETSC_DIR` folder location and `PETSC_ARCH` name in `./configure`. I chose the option of no C++ compilers.

Then `make all` and `make check`. I also did a `make test`, which took quite a while. There were no failures, only success, skip and to do.

`export` `PETSC_DIR` and `PETSC_ARCH` (important for `pets4py`).

### 3) Install `mpi4py` using `pip`

I installed this using `pip`, because `mpi4py` cannot be installed using `conda` while indicating a custom mpicc path, according to the answer to my question provided by Iliev in [this link in Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61013986/13132315).

### 4) Try to install `petsc4py` using `pip`

I wrote using --no-cache-dir:

```
pip install --no-cache-dir petsc4py
```

The build failed. The information displayed in the terminal is shown in the next section.

## IV) The errors

The errors are shown below.

(*Bonus meta question*: is there a way to set automatic line break in the code fences in Stack Overflow?)

```
Collecting petsc4py
  Downloading petsc4py-3.12.0.tar.gz (1.8 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 1.8 MB 2.8 MB/s 
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from petsc4py) (1.18.1)
Building wheels for collected packages: petsc4py
  Building wheel for petsc4py (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /home/breno/anaconda3/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-5qdqmoex/petsc4py/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-5qdqmoex/petsc4py/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-khk8pv9d
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-5qdqmoex/petsc4py/
  Complete output (97 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_src
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/petsc4py
  copying src/PETSc.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/petsc4py
  copying src/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/petsc4py
  copying src/__main__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/petsc4py
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/petsc4py/lib
  copying src/lib/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/petsc4py/lib
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/petsc4py/include
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/petsc4py/include/petsc4py
  copying src/include/petsc4py/petsc4py.PETSc_api.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/petsc4py/include/petsc4py
  copying src/include/petsc4py/petsc4py.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/petsc4py/include/petsc4py
  copying src/include/petsc4py/petsc4py.PETSc.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/petsc4py/include/petsc4py
  copying src/include/petsc4py/numpy.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/petsc4py/include/petsc4py
  copying src/include/petsc4py/petsc4py.i -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/petsc4py/include/petsc4py
  copying src/include/petsc4py/PETSc.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/petsc4py/include/petsc4py
  copying src/include/petsc4py/__init__.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/petsc4py/include/petsc4py
  copying src/include/petsc4py/__init__.pyx -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/petsc4py/include/petsc4py
  copying src/PETSc.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/petsc4py
  copying src/lib/petsc.cfg -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/petsc4py/lib
  running build_ext
  PETSC_DIR:    /home/breno/Documents/petsc
  PETSC_ARCH:   MUMPS-mkl-real-opt
  version:      3.13.0 release
  integer-size: 32-bit
  scalar-type:  real
  precision:    double
  language:     CONLY
  compiler:     /home/breno/.openmpi/bin/mpicc
  linker:       /home/breno/.openmpi/bin/mpicc
  building 'PETSc' extension
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/MUMPS-mkl-real-opt
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/MUMPS-mkl-real-opt/src
  /home/breno/.openmpi/bin/mpicc -pthread -B /home/breno/anaconda3/compiler_compat -Wl,--sysroot=/ -fPIC -Wall -Wwrite-strings -Wno-strict-aliasing -Wno-unknown-pragmas -fstack-protector -O2 -march=native -mtune=native -fPIC -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -I/home/breno/Documents/petsc/MUMPS-mkl-real-opt/include -I/home/breno/Documents/petsc/include -Isrc/include -I/home/breno/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/home/breno/anaconda3/include/python3.7m -c src/PETSc.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/MUMPS-mkl-real-opt/src/PETSc.o
  In file included from src/PETSc.c:4:0:
  src/petsc4py.PETSc.c: In function ‘__pyx_pf_8petsc4py_5PETSc_3Sys_28infoAllow’:
  src/petsc4py.PETSc.c:65427:47: error: too many arguments to function ‘PetscInfoAllow’
     __pyx_t_2 = __pyx_f_8petsc4py_5PETSc_CHKERR(PetscInfoAllow(__pyx_v_tval, NULL)); if (unlikely(__pyx_t_2 == ((int)-1))) __PYX_ERR(27, 163, __pyx_L1_error)
                                                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  In file included from /home/breno/Documents/petsc/include/petscsys.h:1474:0,
                   from /home/breno/Documents/petsc/include/petscbag.h:4,
                   from /home/breno/Documents/petsc/include/petsc.h:5,
                   from src/petsc4py.PETSc.c:596,
                   from src/PETSc.c:4:
  /home/breno/Documents/petsc/include/petsclog.h:56:29: note: declared here
   PETSC_EXTERN PetscErrorCode PetscInfoAllow(PetscBool);
                               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  In file included from src/PETSc.c:4:0:
  src/petsc4py.PETSc.c: In function ‘__pyx_pf_8petsc4py_5PETSc_3Mat_304matMultSymbolic’:
  src/petsc4py.PETSc.c:148044:47: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘MatMatMultSymbolic’; did you mean ‘MatProductSymbolic’? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     __pyx_t_5 = __pyx_f_8petsc4py_5PETSc_CHKERR(MatMatMultSymbolic(__pyx_v_self->mat, __pyx_v_mat->mat, __pyx_v_rval, (&__pyx_v_result->mat))); if (unlikely(__pyx_t_5 == ((int)-1))) __PYX_ERR(36, 1309, __pyx_L1_error)
                                                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                                 MatProductSymbolic
  src/petsc4py.PETSc.c: In function ‘__pyx_pf_8petsc4py_5PETSc_3Mat_306matMultNumeric’:
  src/petsc4py.PETSc.c:148235:47: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘MatMatMultNumeric’; did you mean ‘MatProductNumeric’? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     __pyx_t_4 = __pyx_f_8petsc4py_5PETSc_CHKERR(MatMatMultNumeric(__pyx_v_self->mat, __pyx_v_mat->mat, __pyx_v_result->mat)); if (unlikely(__pyx_t_4 == ((int)-1))) __PYX_ERR(36, 1317, __pyx_L1_error)
                                                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                                 MatProductNumeric
  src/petsc4py.PETSc.c: In function ‘__pyx_pf_8petsc4py_5PETSc_6DMStag_54get1DCoordinateLocationSlot’:
  src/petsc4py.PETSc.c:265960:3: warning: ‘DMStagGet1dCoordinateLocationSlot’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
     __pyx_t_2 = __pyx_f_8petsc4py_5PETSc_CHKERR(DMStagGet1dCoordinateLocationSlot(__pyx_v_self->__pyx_base.dm, __pyx_v_sloc, (&__pyx_v_slot))); if (unlikely(__pyx_t_2 == ((int)-1))) __PYX_ERR(47, 274, __pyx_L1_error)
     ^~~~~~~~~
  In file included from /home/breno/Documents/petsc/include/petsc.h:22:0,
                   from src/petsc4py.PETSc.c:596,
                   from src/PETSc.c:4:
  /home/breno/Documents/petsc/include/petscdmstag.h:127:130: note: declared here
   PETSC_DEPRECATED_FUNCTION("Use DMStagGetProductCoordinateLocationSlot() (since version 3.13") PETSC_STATIC_INLINE PetscErrorCode DMStagGet1dCoordinateLocationSlot(DM dm,DMStagStencilLocation loc,PetscInt *s) {return DMStagGetProductCoordinateLocationSlot(dm,loc,s);}
                                                                                                                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  In file included from src/PETSc.c:4:0:
  src/petsc4py.PETSc.c: In function ‘__pyx_pymod_exec_PETSc’:
  src/petsc4py.PETSc.c:309773:43: error: ‘MATLMVMBRDN’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘MATLMVMBROYDEN’?
     __pyx_t_7 = __pyx_f_8petsc4py_5PETSc_S_(MATLMVMBRDN); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_7)) __PYX_ERR(36, 78, __pyx_L1_error)
                                             ^~~~~~~~~~~
                                             MATLMVMBROYDEN
  src/petsc4py.PETSc.c:309773:43: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
  src/petsc4py.PETSc.c:309785:43: error: ‘MATLMVMBADBRDN’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘MATLMVMBRDN’?
     __pyx_t_7 = __pyx_f_8petsc4py_5PETSc_S_(MATLMVMBADBRDN); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_7)) __PYX_ERR(36, 79, __pyx_L1_error)
                                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                             MATLMVMBRDN
  src/petsc4py.PETSc.c:309797:43: error: ‘MATLMVMSYMBRDN’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘MATLMVMBADBRDN’?
     __pyx_t_7 = __pyx_f_8petsc4py_5PETSc_S_(MATLMVMSYMBRDN); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_7)) __PYX_ERR(36, 80, __pyx_L1_error)
                                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                             MATLMVMBADBRDN
  src/petsc4py.PETSc.c:309809:43: error: ‘MATLMVMSYMBADBRDN’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘MATLMVMSYMBRDN’?
     __pyx_t_7 = __pyx_f_8petsc4py_5PETSc_S_(MATLMVMSYMBADBRDN); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_7)) __PYX_ERR(36, 81, __pyx_L1_error)
                                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                             MATLMVMSYMBRDN
  src/petsc4py.PETSc.c:309821:43: error: ‘MATLMVMDIAGBRDN’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘MATLMVMBADBRDN’?
     __pyx_t_7 = __pyx_f_8petsc4py_5PETSc_S_(MATLMVMDIAGBRDN); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_7)) __PYX_ERR(36, 82, __pyx_L1_error)
                                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                             MATLMVMBADBRDN
  error: command '/home/breno/.openmpi/bin/mpicc' failed with exit status 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for petsc4py
  Running setup.py clean for petsc4py
Failed to build petsc4py
Installing collected packages: petsc4py
    Running setup.py install for petsc4py ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /home/breno/anaconda3/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-5qdqmoex/petsc4py/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-5qdqmoex/petsc4py/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-_npojm20/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/breno/anaconda3/include/python3.7m/petsc4py
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-5qdqmoex/petsc4py/
    Complete output (97 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_src
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/petsc4py
    copying src/PETSc.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/petsc4py
    copying src/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/petsc4py
    copying src/__main__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/petsc4py
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/petsc4py/lib
    copying src/lib/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/petsc4py/lib
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/petsc4py/include
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/petsc4py/include/petsc4py
    copying src/include/petsc4py/petsc4py.PETSc_api.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/petsc4py/include/petsc4py
    copying src/include/petsc4py/petsc4py.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/petsc4py/include/petsc4py
    copying src/include/petsc4py/petsc4py.PETSc.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/petsc4py/include/petsc4py
    copying src/include/petsc4py/numpy.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/petsc4py/include/petsc4py
    copying src/include/petsc4py/petsc4py.i -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/petsc4py/include/petsc4py
    copying src/include/petsc4py/PETSc.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/petsc4py/include/petsc4py
    copying src/include/petsc4py/__init__.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/petsc4py/include/petsc4py
    copying src/include/petsc4py/__init__.pyx -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/petsc4py/include/petsc4py
    copying src/PETSc.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/petsc4py
    copying src/lib/petsc.cfg -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/petsc4py/lib
    running build_ext
    PETSC_DIR:    /home/breno/Documents/petsc
    PETSC_ARCH:   MUMPS-mkl-real-opt
    version:      3.13.0 release
    integer-size: 32-bit
    scalar-type:  real
    precision:    double
    language:     CONLY
    compiler:     /home/breno/.openmpi/bin/mpicc
    linker:       /home/breno/.openmpi/bin/mpicc
    building 'PETSc' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/MUMPS-mkl-real-opt
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/MUMPS-mkl-real-opt/src
    /home/breno/.openmpi/bin/mpicc -pthread -B /home/breno/anaconda3/compiler_compat -Wl,--sysroot=/ -fPIC -Wall -Wwrite-strings -Wno-strict-aliasing -Wno-unknown-pragmas -fstack-protector -O2 -march=native -mtune=native -fPIC -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -I/home/breno/Documents/petsc/MUMPS-mkl-real-opt/include -I/home/breno/Documents/petsc/include -Isrc/include -I/home/breno/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/home/breno/anaconda3/include/python3.7m -c src/PETSc.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/MUMPS-mkl-real-opt/src/PETSc.o
    In file included from src/PETSc.c:4:0:
    src/petsc4py.PETSc.c: In function ‘__pyx_pf_8petsc4py_5PETSc_3Sys_28infoAllow’:
    src/petsc4py.PETSc.c:65427:47: error: too many arguments to function ‘PetscInfoAllow’
       __pyx_t_2 = __pyx_f_8petsc4py_5PETSc_CHKERR(PetscInfoAllow(__pyx_v_tval, NULL)); if (unlikely(__pyx_t_2 == ((int)-1))) __PYX_ERR(27, 163, __pyx_L1_error)
                                                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    In file included from /home/breno/Documents/petsc/include/petscsys.h:1474:0,
                     from /home/breno/Documents/petsc/include/petscbag.h:4,
                     from /home/breno/Documents/petsc/include/petsc.h:5,
                     from src/petsc4py.PETSc.c:596,
                     from src/PETSc.c:4:
    /home/breno/Documents/petsc/include/petsclog.h:56:29: note: declared here
     PETSC_EXTERN PetscErrorCode PetscInfoAllow(PetscBool);
                                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    In file included from src/PETSc.c:4:0:
    src/petsc4py.PETSc.c: In function ‘__pyx_pf_8petsc4py_5PETSc_3Mat_304matMultSymbolic’:
    src/petsc4py.PETSc.c:148044:47: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘MatMatMultSymbolic’; did you mean ‘MatProductSymbolic’? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
       __pyx_t_5 = __pyx_f_8petsc4py_5PETSc_CHKERR(MatMatMultSymbolic(__pyx_v_self->mat, __pyx_v_mat->mat, __pyx_v_rval, (&__pyx_v_result->mat))); if (unlikely(__pyx_t_5 == ((int)-1))) __PYX_ERR(36, 1309, __pyx_L1_error)
                                                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                                   MatProductSymbolic
    src/petsc4py.PETSc.c: In function ‘__pyx_pf_8petsc4py_5PETSc_3Mat_306matMultNumeric’:
    src/petsc4py.PETSc.c:148235:47: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘MatMatMultNumeric’; did you mean ‘MatProductNumeric’? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
       __pyx_t_4 = __pyx_f_8petsc4py_5PETSc_CHKERR(MatMatMultNumeric(__pyx_v_self->mat, __pyx_v_mat->mat, __pyx_v_result->mat)); if (unlikely(__pyx_t_4 == ((int)-1))) __PYX_ERR(36, 1317, __pyx_L1_error)
                                                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                                   MatProductNumeric
    src/petsc4py.PETSc.c: In function ‘__pyx_pf_8petsc4py_5PETSc_6DMStag_54get1DCoordinateLocationSlot’:
    src/petsc4py.PETSc.c:265960:3: warning: ‘DMStagGet1dCoordinateLocationSlot’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
       __pyx_t_2 = __pyx_f_8petsc4py_5PETSc_CHKERR(DMStagGet1dCoordinateLocationSlot(__pyx_v_self->__pyx_base.dm, __pyx_v_sloc, (&__pyx_v_slot))); if (unlikely(__pyx_t_2 == ((int)-1))) __PYX_ERR(47, 274, __pyx_L1_error)
       ^~~~~~~~~
    In file included from /home/breno/Documents/petsc/include/petsc.h:22:0,
                     from src/petsc4py.PETSc.c:596,
                     from src/PETSc.c:4:
    /home/breno/Documents/petsc/include/petscdmstag.h:127:130: note: declared here
     PETSC_DEPRECATED_FUNCTION("Use DMStagGetProductCoordinateLocationSlot() (since version 3.13") PETSC_STATIC_INLINE PetscErrorCode DMStagGet1dCoordinateLocationSlot(DM dm,DMStagStencilLocation loc,PetscInt *s) {return DMStagGetProductCoordinateLocationSlot(dm,loc,s);}
                                                                                                                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    In file included from src/PETSc.c:4:0:
    src/petsc4py.PETSc.c: In function ‘__pyx_pymod_exec_PETSc’:
    src/petsc4py.PETSc.c:309773:43: error: ‘MATLMVMBRDN’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘MATLMVMBROYDEN’?
       __pyx_t_7 = __pyx_f_8petsc4py_5PETSc_S_(MATLMVMBRDN); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_7)) __PYX_ERR(36, 78, __pyx_L1_error)
                                               ^~~~~~~~~~~
                                               MATLMVMBROYDEN
    src/petsc4py.PETSc.c:309773:43: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
    src/petsc4py.PETSc.c:309785:43: error: ‘MATLMVMBADBRDN’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘MATLMVMBRDN’?
       __pyx_t_7 = __pyx_f_8petsc4py_5PETSc_S_(MATLMVMBADBRDN); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_7)) __PYX_ERR(36, 79, __pyx_L1_error)
                                               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                               MATLMVMBRDN
    src/petsc4py.PETSc.c:309797:43: error: ‘MATLMVMSYMBRDN’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘MATLMVMBADBRDN’?
       __pyx_t_7 = __pyx_f_8petsc4py_5PETSc_S_(MATLMVMSYMBRDN); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_7)) __PYX_ERR(36, 80, __pyx_L1_error)
                                               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                               MATLMVMBADBRDN
    src/petsc4py.PETSc.c:309809:43: error: ‘MATLMVMSYMBADBRDN’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘MATLMVMSYMBRDN’?
       __pyx_t_7 = __pyx_f_8petsc4py_5PETSc_S_(MATLMVMSYMBADBRDN); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_7)) __PYX_ERR(36, 81, __pyx_L1_error)
                                               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                               MATLMVMSYMBRDN
    src/petsc4py.PETSc.c:309821:43: error: ‘MATLMVMDIAGBRDN’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘MATLMVMBADBRDN’?
       __pyx_t_7 = __pyx_f_8petsc4py_5PETSc_S_(MATLMVMDIAGBRDN); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_7)) __PYX_ERR(36, 82, __pyx_L1_error)
                                               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                               MATLMVMBADBRDN
    error: command '/home/breno/.openmpi/bin/mpicc' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /home/breno/anaconda3/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-5qdqmoex/petsc4py/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-5qdqmoex/petsc4py/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-_npojm20/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/breno/anaconda3/include/python3.7m/petsc4py Check the logs for full command output.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to install `petsc4py` with the then latest released version **3.12.0** while having installed and configured PETSc version **3.13.0**. This **now** seems quite obvious that it wouldn't work, but there wasn't a clear mention of this in the [documentation](https://petsc4py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).

You can either install the none-released version using `pip install https://bitbucket.org/petsc/petsc4py/issues/137/error-installing-in-anaconda-environment` OR wait for it to be released officially!

## Important conclusion

Make sure that your version of PETSc is the same as `petsc4py`!